# Java FacesContext getRequestParameter not working

Tags: java, jsf, facescontext

I've got the same code on two different machines. One is working the other isn't! The code is here... Anything you could spot that I missed?

```
public void urlParameters() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> paramMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    requestID = paramMap.get("id");
    if (requestID.equals("1")) {
        message = "right!!";           
    } else {
        message = "Wrong!";
    }
}
```

and I access it with this link:

```
http://localhost:8080/SMDRepair/faces/review.xhtml?id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

After long long long research, I found the simplest mean of getting URL parameter in JSF Bean:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")
```

Just make sure you import:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
```

Hope this helps in future

Comment: Yes I know because it even worked smooth on my other machine (linux btw) and don't believe there is OS differences given its java. But just what I tried after worked fine :)